# Changing Column Type in Pandas DataFrame to int64

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, type-conversion, series

I am trying to change a column's data type from `type: object` to `type: int64` within a DataFrame using `.map()`.

```
   df['one'] = df['one'].map(convert_to_int_with_error)
```

Here is my function:

```
def convert_to_int_with_error(x):
    if not x in ['', None, ' ']:
        try:
            return np.int64(x)
        except ValueError as e:
            print(e)
            return None
    else:
        return None

    if not type(x) == np.int64():
        print("Not int64")
        sys.exit()
```

This completes successfully.  However, when I check the data type after completion, it reverts to `type: float`:

```
print("%s is a %s after converting" % (key, df['one'].dtype))
```

Comment: Where exactly did you put the `if not type(x) == np.int64():` condition? Are you saying that `convert_to_int_with_error` never returns `None`?

Comment: For numerical containers, `None` will be regarded as `NaN` so as to keep it's `float`(numerical) dtype. You need to find a way to handle such missing  values/empty strings so that it would result in `np.int64` dtype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think problem is your problematic values are converted from `None` to `NaN`, so `int` is cast to `float` - see [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#na-type-promotions).

Instead `map` you can use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html)  with parameter `errors='coerce'` for convert problematic values to `NaN`:

```
df['one'] = pd.to_numeric(df['one'], errors='coerce')
```

Comment: I included the try and except to account for values that could not be converted to int64 properly though?

Comment: Unfortunately is not possible have `dtype` `int` with `NaN` or `None` values.